# Where do I edit manifest.webapp

Tags: cordova, manifest, firefox-os

I'm using cordova to package my app, but I'm unable to modify a `manifest.webapp`, specifically adding icons, so that the changes are included when I run

```
cordova build firefoxos
```

I've tried to edit `platforms/firefoxos/www/manifest.webapp` but these changes are lost when I run `cordova build firefoxos`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are working on the merge issue currently.  As a work around you can just add a completed manifest.webapp to the merges/firefoxos directory and it will be pushed to the output.  See the last note of the sample app here:
https://github.com/mozilla-cordova/cordovasample

Answer (score 1):

Icons can be added in `config.xml`:

```
<icon src="Logo.png" platform="firefoxos" width="128" height="128" density="mdpi" />
```

Which will generate the following in manifest.webapp

```
"icons": {
    "128": "/icon-128.png"
},
```

Comment: The OP did not ask about adding icons.

Comment: Adding icons is a significant part of the manifest, this is how it is done. If I find that it is possible to add more properties to manifest.webapp by editing config.xml I will add them here too, but for now this is what can be done.

Comment: @Stonz2 - this is an answer **from the OP** themselves, they have a better idea of what is relevant to it that you do!

Comment: @ChrisStratton obviously I was not the only person to think this- I just call it like I see it when reviewing.

Comment: That's why you often need to be more careful if you are going to be wielding a reviewer's hammer.  If you could see the question to claim that this seemed unrelated, then you could see the matching authorship too.

Comment: I was suggested to add another, more specific question about icons, but that one would have been worded almost exactly the same so I just modified this question. I still consider Jasons answer better since it is more general.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than manually copying the file every time you build, I've set up an alias as a workaround.

More specifically I did the following:

```
vim .bashrc
alias ffos="cordova prepare firefoxos && \cp -f  www/manifest.webapp platforms/firefoxos/www/manifest.webapp --verbose"
source .bashrc
```

I guess you could do either `cordova build` or `cordova prepare`. If you want to see the full context, here's a [blogpost](http://www.dhfromkorea.com/how-to-edit-manifest-dot-webapp-when-using-cordova-for-firefox-os/) I wrote.